# select radio button on prefix in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three radio button

```
<input type=radio id=pp />Product
<input type=radio id=pr />Price
<input type=radio id=bb />both
```

So if I click on product it is showing me product, if I select price it is showing price of product , if both showing both price and product for the product which i enter in text box.

What I want if I  am using only keyboard , I type some  prefix in text box like pp for product , pr for price and bb for both. So if pp then radio Product should get selected and others de-select. want same for others

Comment: Did you try to do so? Be more specific.

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this you can easily achieve with jQuery.

have same name or class for all textbox which you want to run the functionality and make following code

```
$(function() {
    $(".classnameoftextbox").change(function() {
        var txtVal = $(this).val();
        try  {
            $("#"+ txtVal).attr('selected', true);
        }
        catch(ex)  {}
    });
});
```

Comment: @vishal_g can you please vote for my answer and mark as Answer?

Comment: I can't vote , i don't have that much of reputaion to vote and let me know how to mark as answer. So that i can mark u as answer

Comment: @vishal_g the reason I am asking is someone also will use this code. just click on the tick mark behind my Answer then it shows green tick mark finally refresh the page to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I type some prefix in text box like pp for product , pr for price and bb for both. So if pp then radio Product should get selected and others de-select. want same for others**

```
   <input type="text" id="mytext" onkeyup="checkRadio(this);"/>
    <input type=radio id=pp name='filterchk'/>Product 
    <input type=radio id=pr name='filterchk'/>Price 
    <input type=radio id=bb name='filterchk' checked="checked"/>both
<script>
function checkRadio(obj){
    var t = obj.value;
    if(t.substr(0,2)=='pp'){
        document.getElementById('pp').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('pr').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('bb').checked = false;
        }
    else if(t.substr(0,2)=='pr'){
        document.getElementById('pp').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('pr').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('bb').checked = false;
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById('pp').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('pr').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('bb').checked = true;
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could check out jQuery, and especially keyboard events and how to use them... That way you wouldn't have to use a text input box.

The other way would be to put a function in the onchange event to check if the string in the box matches the suffix, and if it does, change the radio button selection.

Comment: The fact that it is not needed does not mean it's not a valid option. Anyway, i changed my answer with an alternative...

Comment: It is a valid option, but it is not an answer. If someone has a hammer and a nail, and asks you how to put that nail into a wood plank, would you recommend a better hammer or would you show him how to hammer?

Comment: I still think that in questions as vague as this it's better to nudge the student into the right direction than provide a ready made solution. As i said, a non jQuery option was added to my answer.

Comment: By the way: jQuery is an awesome hammer, so naturally i'm looking for nails!